# How interrupt/stop a thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to stop a thread but I can't do that :

```
public class Middleware {

public void read() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.8", 2001);

        // code .. 

        Scan scan = new Scan();
        thread = new Thread(scan);
        thread.start();

    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class Scan extends Thread {

    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
            // my code goes here

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void stop() {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}

// get and setters
}
```

So, even when i call the method 'stop' the thread don't stop.
It keeps alive.

How can I interrupt/stop this thread ?

**UPDATE**
(@little approach)

```
private void tb_startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Middleware middleware = new Middleware();

    if (tb_start.getText().equals("Start")){
        tb_start.setText("Stop");

        // starting to read rfid tags
        middleware.read();
    }else{
        tb_start.setText("Start");

        // stop reading rfid tags
        middleware.stop();
    }
}
```

The Middleware class :

```
public class Middleware {

    private Scan scan;

    public void read() {

        scan = new Scan();
        scan.start();
    }

    private class Scan extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("reading...");
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (scan != null) {
            scan.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to stop the thread, it doesn't.

What could be wrong in the code above ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping a Thread in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247455/stopping-a-thread-in-java)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's really no reason you need to use a `volatile` flag. Instead, just query the thread for its state with [`isInterrupted()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29). Also, why are you wrapping your `Scan` thread object in another thread object? That seems completely unnecessary to me.

Here' what you should be doing

```
public class Middleware {
    private Scan scan;

    public void read() {
        try {
            // do stuff

            scan = new Scan();
            scan.start();
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception
        }
    }

    private class Scan extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    // my code goes here
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if(scan != null){
            scan.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915156/how-can-i-kill-a-thread-without-using-stop/5915430#5915430). Also, I wouldn't recommend extending `Thread`.

Comment: What about the possible SecurityException of interrupt? `Unless the current thread is interrupting itself, which is always permitted, the checkAccess method of this thread is invoked, which may cause a SecurityException to be thrown.`

Comment: After Thread was interrupted by interrupt() how can one start it again  , meaning resume it.

Comment: "There's really no reason you need to use a volatile flag."                                                                                 Actually that's not really true.  The circumstances under which the interrupt flag is cleared are pretty confusing, and if the code in the thread calls any 3rd party libraries, there's a good chance calling `theThread.interrupt()` won't actually work.

Comment: @BobbyBrown I answered this a while ago, but IIRC it has something to do with preferring composition over inheritance.  But as a quick and dirty solution, it's fine.

Answer (score 11):

Simply `return;` from your while and the thread will die, no need to call stop() or interrupt(). If you want to do it externally then use this pattern and call `requestStop()`.

```
class Scan extends Thread {
    private volatile stop = false;
    public void run() {

        while (!stop) {
            try {
            // my code goes here

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                stop = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void requestStop() {
        stop = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: If there was a blocking code in the try, like waiting for connection to be accepted or scanner.nextLine() that waits for input, will this code still work?

Comment: You can add an `interrupt()` call after setting stop to true in the requestStop method.

Comment: If you don't use volatile you are not guaranteed to see the latest state of the field since a previous state might be cached by the current thread.

Answer (score 5):

"Many uses of `stop()` should be replaced by code that simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running."—[`java.lang.Thread`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to stop a thread is to have a volatile flag and then check that in the run method. i.e.

```
class Scan extends Thread {
    volatile stop = false;
    public void run() {

        while (!stop) {
            try {
            // my code goes here

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop(){
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

You can then call `scan.stop()`.

Comment: in your case you would need to set stop to true in the catch instead of calling interrupt

Comment: volative stop can be an attribute ?
so i can call a method 'stop' to change the value from it ?

Comment: If there was a blocking code in the try, like waiting for connection to be accepted or scanner.nextLine() that waits for input from keyboard, will this code still work?

Comment: Why `volatile`, why not just a regular, private variable?

Comment: @raffian Threads have a local copy of variables which may not have the latest value of a variable. Volatile will ensure that`stop` will not use a cached value.

Comment: This is not working. Telling me to remove the try/catch clause.

Comment: @KarlMorrison The try catch is from the original askers code. It's not needed and can be removed if your code doesn't throw an `IOException`.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to interrupt a running thread, then you need to have access to the thread object.

```
thread = new Thread(scan);
thread.start();
```

then say

```
thread.interrupt();
```

this will interrupt the running thread.

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with Jim.. Just to add If your thread is blocked inside the try block
for instance reading on a datastream etc then interrupt the thread as well or close
the stream. In both cases the thread should be wakened up again and it will then be able to see the change in the value of "stop" boolean and die naturally by falling out of the run method. At least this is what I did to kill my threads in the shutdown thread for my server.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void run()
    { 
         while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) 
         {
        //do something here
        if(condition)
       {
           Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Could you please specify a bit more about your answer? It's usually good form to add some sort of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Thread.stop() or Thread.interrupt() you can go for the external locks. Basically, when you try to utilize an intrinsic lock most of the time any interrupt you perform on the thread is uncontrollable.

A re-entrant lock provides you the methods as mentioned below

```
lock() 
unlock() 
tryLock() 
lockInterruptibly() 
isHeldByCurrentThread() 
getHoldCount()
```

Check the below example

```
final ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();    
    @Override
    public void performTask() {
        reentrantLock.lock();
        try { 
             System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Lock acquired.");
             System.out.println("Processing...");
             Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
             System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Lock released.");
         reentrantLock.unlock();
            }
    }
```

This makes your code elegant and handle the interrupt in a better way.