# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.util.Random

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package com.nodic.test;

import java.util.Random;

public class StopThread {
  private static User user = new User();

  public static class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public User() {
      id  = 1;
      name = "1";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "{id=" + id + ", name=\"" + name + "\"}";
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
    }
  }

  public static class WriteThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      while(true) {
        synchronized (user) {
          int curr_id = new Random().nextInt();

          user.setId(curr_id);

          try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

          user.setName(String.valueOf(curr_id));
        }

        Thread.yield();
      }
    }
  }

  public static class ReadThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      while (true) {
        synchronized (user) {
          if(!user.getName().equals(String.valueOf(user.getId()))) {
            System.out.println(user.toString());
            break;
          }
        }

        Thread.yield();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new ReadThread(), "Thread-StopThread-ReadThread").start();

    int count = 0;

    while(count < 50) {
      Thread t = new Thread(new WriteThread(), "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread");
      t.start();

      t.stop();

      count ++;
    }
  }
}
```

HI every one, when i run this class with jdk1.8.0_45, why i always got this error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.util.Random

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IDE/IntelliJ IDEA /IntelliJ
>   IDEA 14.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/huangshiqian/Workspaces/IDEA/Test/concurrent/target/classes:/Users/huangshiqian/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.9/junit-4.9.jar:/Users/huangshiqian/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.1/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar:/Applications/IDE/IntelliJ
>   IDEA /IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar"
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain
>   com.nodic.test.StopThread
>
> Exception: java.lang.ThreadDeath thrown from the
>   UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread"
>
> Exception: java.lang.ThreadDeath thrown from the
>   UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread"
>   Exception in thread "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" Exception in
>   thread "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread"  Exception:
>   java.lang.ThreadDeath thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in
>   thread "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" Exception in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" Exception in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" Exception in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" Exception in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread"  Exception: java.lang.ThreadDeath
>   thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread"
>
> Exception: java.lang.ThreadDeath thrown from the
>   UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread"
>
> Exception: java.lang.ThreadDeath thrown from the
>   UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread"
>
> Exception: java.lang.ThreadDeath thrown from the
>   UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread"
>
> Exception: java.lang.ThreadDeath thrown from the
>   UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread"
>   Exception in thread "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   java.util.Random  at
>   com.nodic.test.StopThread$WriteThread.run(StopThread.java:44)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Exception in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class java.util.Random     at
>   com.nodic.test.StopThread$WriteThread.run(StopThread.java:44)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Exception in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class java.util.Random     at
>   com.nodic.test.StopThread$WriteThread.run(StopThread.java:44)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Exception in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class java.util.Random     at
>   com.nodic.test.StopThread$WriteThread.run(StopThread.java:44)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Exception in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class java.util.Random     at
>   com.nodic.test.StopThread$WriteThread.run(StopThread.java:44)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Exception in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class java.util.Random     at
>   com.nodic.test.StopThread$WriteThread.run(StopThread.java:44)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Exception in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class java.util.Random     at
>   com.nodic.test.StopThread$WriteThread.run(StopThread.java:44)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Exception in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class java.util.Random     at
>   com.nodic.test.StopThread$WriteThread.run(StopThread.java:44)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Exception in thread
>   "Thread-StopThread-WriteThread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class java.util.Random     at
>   com.nodic.test.StopThread$WriteThread.run(StopThread.java:44)

Comment: Any problem for not setting JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Don't, ever, use Thread.stop(). Read its javadoc.

Comment: you didn't include java.lang.Thread and you didn't handled any exceptions,that could be your problem and i also agree with SMA,Are you sure you've set JAVA_HOME?

Comment: i run it with intellij idea,  and already set java_home in my environment 
echo $JAVA_HOME

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: just test Thread.stop()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How interrupt/stop a thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599202/java-how-interrupt-stop-a-thread)

Comment: this program is used to test why Thread.stop() is unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely called `stop()` on a thread while it was running the static initialization for the `Random` class.

- The JVM only attempts to initialize a class once.
- If a classes initialization fails (because an exception was thrown), the JVM marks it, and any classes that depend on it ... as "bad".  If you attempt to use it / them, you get a `ClassDefNotFoundError`.
- The implementation for `Thread.stop()` is to cause the `ThreadDeath` exception to be thrown on the stack of the target thread.

In short, this is an example which illustrates why calling `Thread.stop()` is unsafe.