# How to stop a thread and invoke another

Tags: java

My program running on a one thread. And I have another thread and I want to stop current thread and invoke the second thread. And after second thread stops I want to invoke the first thread again. How can I do this. Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping a Thread in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247455/stopping-a-thread-in-java)

Comment: When you say invoke thread again, you mean restart it from beginning ? Or resume it ? If you start it again, just reinstanciante and start after having killed the previous ones as in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `public final void join(long ms);` method. Invoke it in your current thread.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [Thread.join](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29) method

like this (thread2 is the other thread you wanna wait for)

```
thread2.start();
thread2.join();
System.out.println("Done");
```