# HowTo- thread stop

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

just a little question, i want to stiop the following thread, but i have no idea how i should do. Please help me. Googles help wasnt useful this time.

```
new Thread(){
    public void run() {
        while(!isInterrupted()){
            try {
                if (sock1!=null){
                    sock1.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                    if (btsar1.length > 0) {
                        dos1 = new DataOutputStream(sock1.getOutputStream());
                        bwrtr1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                dos1), 300);
                        dos1.write(btsar1);
                            set1free = false;
                    Log.e("Communication", "written(1.1)");
                        Reader1.reader(4);}
                    }} catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (NullPointerException e2){
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
}}.start();
//.interrupt(); <-- or kinda that...
```

Can someone provide a good working thing, to stop this?

Comment: *"Pls help me."*   Please spell words properly.  This is not a text message.

Comment: sorry, my fault... am a little in a hurry ^^

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java

Comment: a very good article: http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping a Thread in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247455/stopping-a-thread-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to terminate a thread is to let it finish. So add a boolean flag in your `while`, and have method (or otherwise) expose it so it can be set to false. Then your thread would naturally exit after the interation has finished.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a reference to your thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(...);
```

Then you can interrupt it:

```
t.interrupt();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
      ... // content unchanged
};
t.start();
.....
t.interrupt();
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea: **stop using anonymous threads**!

Whenever you find yourself in a situation where your thread is doing something complicated, either create a separate class extending the thread, which can be used to control and monitor the behaviour, or use an abstract Future and a ThreadPool to do the work.

You will have an extremely unmaintainable and unextendable code if you keep using threads like this.

**How to stop a thread gracefully?**

```
bool keepWorking = true;

while(keepWorking) {
  // keep working
}

synchronized void stopWork() {
  keepWorking = false;
}

// in other thread
threadObj.stopWork();
```

Comment: His way of doing it: `while(!interrupted)` is better than introducing an additional unnecessary boolean flag. Especially with interruptable I/O methods.

Comment: the threads name is given in another activity, where it is called from

Answer (score 0):

***`Thread.interrupt`*** method is for to stop a thread that waits for long periods (e.g., for input)

Take a look at this Article - **[How to Stop a Thread or a Task](http://www.forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html)**

example

---

```
public void stop() {
            Thread moribund = waiter;
            waiter = null;
            moribund.interrupt();
        }
```

---