# How to stop thread in java

Tags: java, swing

I create an alarm clock that rings an alarm until the puzzle is solve I have a play class that play alarm 
    `
     package clock;

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Play {
AudioClip ac;
Thread t;
public void playSound(int n)
{
     try {
        URL url = new URL("file:1.wav" );
        ac = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
        t= new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                ac.loop();
            }
        };
        if(n==0){
            t.start();
        }
        if (n==1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"OFF");
            ac.stop();
            t.interrupt();
        }
    } 
     catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); 
    }
}`
```

it play alarm on time but when i call it with parameter 1 it shows "OFF" but alarm thread is not stop

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247455/stopping-a-thread-in-java

Comment: If I use while loop in this case then it restarts sound every time when loop restarts.

Answer (score 1):

> I create an alarm clock that rings an alarm until the puzzle is solve

You can try with [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) that is most suitable for swing application.

Read more [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

---

Play sound at fix interval and stop the timer once puzzle is solved. Just set the flag `isSolved` to `true` and swing timer will be stopped.

**Sample code:**

```
private Timer timer;
private volatile boolean isSolved;
...

// interval of 1 second
timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        if(isSolved){
           // stop the timer
            timer.stop();
        }else{
            // play sound
        }
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(true); // you can turn off it 
timer.start();
```

Comment: I have updated my post. just set the flag and stop the swing timer.

Answer (score -1):

In your code for the thread add a bolean value running, and when run() is called set it to true. Create an additional method, stopRun() and use this to stop the thread.

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        private bolean run;

        public void run(){
           while(run){
               //code
            }
        }

  public void stopRun(){
      this.run = false;
    }
  }
);
```